# NodeJS Queue System for Connections Past 20

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I'm trying to create a queue system in NodeJS so that only 20 connections are able to access a certain page at once.  Right now I'm assigning each user a unique ID using [shortid](https://www.npmjs.com/package/shortid) and javascript localStorage (to store their ID).  I want to give each user 1 minute to see the piece of content and then it boots them to "get back in line".  If they have to wait it will tell them "You'll be connected in XX minutes".

Right now my process is to use `http.globalAgent.maxSockets = 20;` to only allow 20 people in but it's not allowing me to route them somewhere else to make them wait.  My thought was to have a database of what order people are "in line".  Then when a user is kicked off the page after 1 minute, the next user "in line" will be brought in and given 1 minute before they are kicked out.

I'm using MySQL to store the queue.  The problem is I'm not sure how to finish the code to boot someone after one minute and make them "get back in line".  Any help?  Thanks!

Comment: It is not clear exactly what you're trying to control.  Are you trying to control how many people can view a page at the same time?  Because viewing has nothing to do with `http.globalAgent.maxSockets` and is not something your server can directly control at all.  A browser viewing a regular web page is NOT connected to the server while just viewing.  One or more connections are made to retrieve the page contents, then the connections are closed after the page contents have been retrieved.  This works slightly differently in different versions of HTTP.

Comment: Why would you use localStorage? A cookie would suffice, and has better browser compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're misunderstanding the HTTP protocol. When you make an HTTP request, a TCP connection is created, but not held. You also cannot just limit the sockets for a single route. HTTP is not a persistent connection. You'll need to find another way to implement such a system. Being that HTTP is stateless and non-persistent it will be difficult to do correctly. So if you limit your maxSockets to 20, that means that you can only accept 20 requests at a time. A socket is created for a request/response, but does not persist after that even if the user is still views the page.

You'd probably need a way to "check-in" a user to that page. Something that comes to mind would be to have the users connect to a web socket when they reach that page, and each time a user attempts to join then send out a broadcast to all the users on that page to see how many are still on it. This would still be easily fooled unless you served the pages content over the websocket, because I could simple disable websockets or load a script to just disconnect from the websocket so it cannot "put me back in line". It's likely a very complicated solution, because you're trying to manage the state of your clients, and that's not something HTTP is good at on its own.